# mongodb restore multiple collections with one command

Tags: mongodb

**How do I restore multiple collections at once in mongodb.**

I have tried

```
mongorestore -c Role -c UserAccount -c Permission -d movie-app dump/
```

and I got an error `file dump is a directory, not a bson file`

I can restore single collection at a time I have to  specify the bson file like

```
  mongorestore -c UserAccount -d movie-app dump/movie-app/UserAccount.bson
```

I need to know how do I ***restore multiple collection with one command.***

Comment: As per mongo Documentation - mongorestore --port <port number> <path to the backup> reference URL https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/

Comment: That is how to restore full database, but I want to restore only some collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v3.4 you can use the `--nsExclude` and/or `--nsInclude` options to create a superset of the functionality of the `--collection` option

For example:

```
// only restore documents in the transactions database 
// and exclude collections whose name ends with "_dev"
mongorestore --nsInclude 'transactions.*' --nsExclude 'transactions.*_dev' dump/
```

More details in [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#example-basic-wildcard-usage).

**Update** in response to this comment:

> hmm but the collections names I want to restore have no any similar pattern to use wild cards..

If the collection names you do **not** want to restore can be isolated using a wildcard pattern then you could just use `--nsExclude`. If not, then `mongorestore` cannot do what you want in a single call so instead you could invoke `mongorestore` in a loop within a batch or shell script, invoking `mongorestore` once for each of the collection names you want to restore.

Comment: hmm but the collections names I want to restore have no any similar pattern to use wild cards..

Comment: Could I simply call `--nsInclude` (or `--nsExclude`) multiple times?

Comment: @toto_tico yes as per https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#:~:text=%20multiple%20times%20to%20exclude%20multiple%20namespace%20patterns.